# Determine a binary tree is balanced or not

Tags: python, binary-tree

Basically, this code is to determine if a binary tree is height-balanced. Here is my code.

```
class Solution:
    """
    @param root: The root of binary tree.
    @return: True if this Binary tree is Balanced, or false.
    """
    def isBalanced(self, root):
        # write your code here
        if root is None:
            return

        left_height = self.findHeight(root.left)
        right_height = self.findHeight(root.right)
        print(root.val,left_height,right_height)
        self.isBalanced(root.left)
        self.isBalanced(root.right)
        if abs(left_height - right_height) > 1:
            return False
        return abs(left_height - right_height) <= 1

    def findHeight(self, root):
        if root is None:
            return 0
        left_height = self.findHeight(root.left)
        right_height = self.findHeight(root.right)
        height = max(left_height, right_height) + 1
        return height
```

For the binary tree in following pic [Binary tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7qRH.png) The result of print is

```
1 3 3
2 2 0
4 1 1
7 0 0
8 0 0
3 2 2
5 1 1
9 0 0
10 0 0
6 1 1
11 0 0
12 0 0
```

For node 2, `left_height` is 2 and its `right_height` is 0, the difference is bigger than 1 and should return `False`. But this code returns `True` and I was confused.

Comment: You call `self.isBalanced(root.left)` and `self.isBalanced(root.right)` but never do anything with their return values.

Comment: @Aran-Fey hmmm, I see. That may cause the problem. But according to the printed result, doesn't it go into the if condition (since the difference is greater than 1)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code only checks if the heights at the top of the tree are correct. You need to take into account the results of the subtrees.

This

```
self.isBalanced(root.left)
self.isBalanced(root.right)
if abs(left_height - right_height) > 1:
    return False
```

Should be this

```
return (
    self.isBalanced(root.left) and
    self.isBalanced(root.right) and
    abs(left_height - right_height) <= 1
)
```